# Format text display for values echoed from mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

When i enter a value like  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr in a textarea on my form,upon echoing it, it displays as a single line someone help sort this cozy it's deforming my table. Your help is so much welcome

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `word-break: break-all` css property value on the large table cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/GgqL4/

Comment: Yeah finally i used i modified the code here http://jsfiddle.net/GgqL4/ Pills to 
.spc {
    width: 500px;
    table-layout: fixed;
 
    word-break: break-all;

} 

included it in my css and called it. thing got sorted thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything you can do about that, other than to truncate the characters or break it apart after X number of characters. Id' truncate...

```
function truncate_chars($string, $limit, $break=' ', $pad='...') {
    // return with no change if string is shorter than $limit
    if(strlen($string) <= $limit) return $string;

        $string = substr($string, 0, $limit);
        if(false !== ($breakpoint = strrpos($string, $break))) {
         $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint);
     }
     return $string . $pad;
}

echo truncate_chars($string);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, can't i like format the text after it has been echoed?

Comment: Not really, because the browser rendering engine sees this as one word and it doesn't want to break the word. You'd have to break it yourself, either by truncating it or breaking it apart (perhaps hyphenating it) after x number of characters. I've seen facebook posts with this exact same problem - it breaks their layout too.

Comment: CSS isn't 100% reliable, so I did a little digging and also came up with wordwrap() http://us2.php.net/wordwrap.